# Rotations of spin eigenstates in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin, rotation, bloch-sphere

If you have a state $| \psi \rangle = | \uparrow \rangle$ which is the spin eignstate of the spin operator $\hat{S}_z = \frac{\hbar}{2} \hat{\sigma}_{z}$ then if you view this state as a vector in the Bloch sphere, and you are interested in rotating the spin state by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ around the $x$ axis, as I understand you apply the operator $\hat{U} = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}\hat{\sigma}_x}$, would you then obtain $$\hat{U}| \uparrow \rangle = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}\hat{\sigma}_x}| \uparrow \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}| \uparrow \rangle + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}| \downarrow \rangle?$$

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I believe that you are missing a factor of $\imath$ in your expression for $U$. Have you tried calculating $U|\uparrow\rangle$ directly?

Comment: @BySymmetry Yeah that was a typo. You mean by expaning $e^{...}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to expand the exponential, using
$\sigma_x=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and remembering that $\sigma_x^2=1_{2\times 2}$.  Thus
\begin{align}
e^{-i\theta  \sigma_x}&= 1_{2\times 2}-i\theta\sigma_x +\frac{1}{2}
(-1)\theta^2 1_{2\times 2} +\frac{1}{3!}i\theta^3\sigma_x+\ldots\, ,\\
&=1_{2\times 2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}{\theta^2}+\ldots\right)-i\sigma_x
\left(\theta-\frac{1}{3!}\theta^3+\ldots\right)\, ,\\
&=1_{2\times2}\cos\theta-i\sigma_x\sin(\theta)\, ,\\
&=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (\theta ) & -i \sin (\theta ) \\
 -i \sin (\theta ) & \cos (\theta ) \\
\end{array}
\right)\, .
\end{align}
The result you are looking for follows by using $\theta=\pi/4$ (*NOT* $\theta=\pi/2$) and acting on $\vert\uparrow\rangle=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0 \end{array}\right)$.  Using $\theta=\pi/2$ yields $i\vert\downarrow\rangle$.

It may be that the discrepancy between my result and yours comes in the definition of $\sigma_x$, which is sometimes confused for $S_x=\sigma_x/2$.

Comment: Okay thanks for a very good answer. Just two quick things: Firstly, when considering $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ I now get $e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}\sigma_x}| \uparrow\rangle = e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}\sigma_x}\dbinom{1}{0} = \dbinom{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}| \uparrow \rangle - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}| \downarrow \rangle$. Hence am I right in stating that we have rotated $| \uparrow \rangle$ to the eigenstate corresponding to the spin down eigenstate of $\hat{S}_y$?

Comment: Lastly, considering two spin up particles, would this be correct $$e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}\sigma_{x_1}}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}\sigma_{x_2}}[|\uparrow \rangle \otimes |\uparrow \rangle ] = [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}| \uparrow \rangle - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}| \downarrow \rangle] \otimes [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}| \uparrow \rangle - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}| \downarrow \rangle] \\= \frac{1}{2} | \uparrow \rangle \otimes | \uparrow \rangle - \frac{i}{2}| \uparrow \rangle \otimes | \downarrow\rangle -\frac{i}{2}| \downarrow \rangle \otimes | \uparrow \rangle - \frac{1}{2}| \downarrow \rangle \otimes | \downarrow \rangle?$$

Comment: I believe yes on both counts.